# How to save html page rendered through WebView into a bitmap while the WebView is part of an activity with Theme.NoDisplay?

Tags: android, webview, themes

I know how to do that while the `WebView` is part of an activity which is visible. I have my own `MyWebView` class that extends `WebView`. There I have my own overriden `onDraw` and `invalidate` methods (see below). This seems to work well.

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView {
    private static final String TAG = MyWebView.class.getName();

    private Canvas offscreen;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;

    public MyWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // We want the superclass to draw directly to the offscreen canvas
        // so that we don't get an infinitely deep recursive call
        if(canvas == offscreen) {
            super.onDraw(offscreen);
        } else {
            //Our offscreen image uses the dimensions of the view rather than the canvas
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            offscreen = new Canvas(bitmap);
            super.onDraw(offscreen);
            Log.d(TAG, "Drew canvas into a bitmap");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();

        if ((getContentHeight() > 0) && (getProgress() == 100)) {
            // WebView has displayed some content
            // Now is the time to store the bitmap into a file
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "image.jpeg";
            File imageFile = new File(path);

            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "Image stored into : " + path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String eMessage = "Unable to save the image into: " + e.toString();
                Log.e(TAG, eMessage);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (fos != null) {
                        fos.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String eMessage = "Something went really wrong. Unable to close FileOutputStream: " + e.toString();
                    Log.e(TAG, eMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to do this within an activity which does not have UI, for instance one that has theme set to `Theme.NoDisplay`.

Can anyone help me with that please?

For the activity where the theme is set to `Theme.NoDisplay` it seems like the `onDraw` method is never called while `invalidate` is called several times.

How to force the system to call the `onDraw` method even in an activity without UI?

I will be also very glad for any other approach how to get an html page rendered/saved into a bitmap. All has to happen as a background task without a user to even noticing it. `WebView` is probably not a must have but to me it seems very useful.

Answer (score 0):

After my investigation the solution is following:

I had to call the WebView's draw method directly. With this the onDraw method is also called and the bitmap is created. The problem is where and when to call the draw method.

After endless experiments with onPageFinished, javascript interface listenning to onload event and others I was not able to find an elegant solution. Nothing really worked as all the hooks are fired before the resources are physically on the device. So all the time the bitmap was empty.

So in the end the only way it worked for me was when I called the draw method within onPageFinished with some delay. I actually created my own draw method which does not take any parameter. This one simply calles the WebView's method with the bitmap canvas.

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            handler = new Handler();
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if ((webView != null)) {
                        // Draw the page into a bitmap
                        webView.draw();

                        // After the bitmap is fully drawn, save the image
                        webView.saveImage();

                        // Finish the helper activity
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
        }
    });
```

It works on all the devices I've tested with (even with older versions like Jelly Beans).

The only problems I can see with this solution is that

- I do not have the image instantly once the page resources are really fully loaded into WebView (I really do not know what event I should listent to. I am now suspecting google not to have one reliable available in Android).
- I have an invisible activity which is hanging in the system for 2 seconds everytime I need to create an image